Getting Invalid signature in the Third step of Netsuite 3 step Authorization flow
I am following the 3 step authorization flow using PHP/Laravel. I have been able to pass step one and two which is getting the unauthorized token and redirecting the user to the netsuite login form. After the redirecting the user, I am able to login, put my 2FA from my authenticator app. After that it tells me to 'allow' or 'deny' the application, I click on allow. After clicking on allow I get a 'USER_ERROR' 'Invalid attempt to login'. I also get an InvalidSignature error in my Audit trail. below is the code I am using.
Basically this is my company's Netsuite account in production. I created two users, an admin and a user which just has a TBA role for testing the 3 step authorization flow. So for testing purposes, I am trying to log into the account using token based authentication. I created an integration, I also created an Access Token assigned to the user and assigned to the created integration. what could be the issue and how can I resolve the InvalidSignature error. Please any help will be appreciated.
class NetSuiteIntegrationHelper
{
    protected $config;

    protected static $lastTimestamp;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->config = [
            'consumer_key' => env('NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY'),
            'consumer_secret' => env('NETSUITE_CONSUMER_SECRET'),
            'token_secret' => env('NETSUITE_TOKEN_SECRET'),
            'token_id' => env('NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID'),
        ];

        if (! $this->config['consumer_key'] || ! $this->config['consumer_secret']) {
            throw new \Exception('NetSuite consumer key or secret is not set in .env file');
        }
    }

    private function getCurrentTimestamp()
    {
        $pacificTime = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));

        $currentTimestamp = $pacificTime->getTimestamp();

        if ($currentTimestamp <= self::$lastTimestamp) {
            $currentTimestamp = self::$lastTimestamp + 1;
        }

        self::$lastTimestamp = $currentTimestamp;

        return $currentTimestamp;
    }

    public function getUnauthorizedRequestToken($callbackUrl, $accountId, $role = null)
    {
        $params = [
            'oauth_callback' => $callbackUrl,
            'oauth_consumer_key' => $this->config['consumer_key'],
            'oauth_nonce' => $this->generateNonce(),
            'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA256',
            'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
            'oauth_version' => '1.0',
        ];

        $baseString = $this->buildBaseString('POST', "https://{$accountId}.restlets.api.netsuite.com/rest/requesttoken", $params);

        $compositeKey = $this->config['consumer_secret'].'&';

        $params['oauth_signature'] = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $baseString, $compositeKey, true));

        $header = 'OAuth '.$this->buildAuthorizationHeader($params);

        $response = Http::withHeaders(['Authorization' => $header])
            ->post("https://{$accountId}.restlets.api.netsuite.com/rest/requesttoken");

        if ($response->failed()) {
            dump($response);

            return ['error' => $response->body()];
        }

        return $this->parseResponse($response->body());
    }

    public function getAccessToken($token, $verifier, $accountId)
    {
        $params = [
            'oauth_token' => $token,
            'oauth_verifier' => $verifier,
            'oauth_consumer_key' => $this->config['consumer_key'],
            'oauth_nonce' => $this->generateNonce(),
            'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA256',
            'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
            'oauth_version' => '1.0',
            'realm' => $accountId,
        ];

        $baseString = $this->buildBaseString('POST', "https://{$accountId}.restlets.api.netsuite.com/rest/accesstoken", $params);

        $compositeKey = rawurlencode($this->config['consumer_secret']).'&'.rawurlencode($this->config['token_secret']);

        $signedBasedString = hash_hmac('sha256', $baseString, $compositeKey, true);

        $signature = base64_encode($signedBasedString);

        $params['oauth_signature'] = $signature;

        $header = 'OAuth '.$this->buildAuthorizationHeader($params);

        $response = Http::withHeaders(['Authorization' => $header])
            ->post("https://{$accountId}.restlets.api.netsuite.com/rest/accesstoken");

        if ($response->failed()) {
            dump($response, $this->config['consumer_secret'], $this->config['token_secret']);

            return ['error' => $response->body()];
        }

        return $this->parseResponse($response->body());
    }

    private function buildBaseString($method, $url, $params)
    {
        if (isset($params['realm'])) {
            unset($params['realm']);
        }

        ksort($params);
        $paramString = [];

        foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            $paramString[] = $key.'='.rawurlencode($value);
        }

        $baseString = strtoupper($method).'&'.rawurlencode($url).'&'.rawurlencode(implode('&', $paramString));

        return $baseString;
    }

    private function buildAuthorizationHeader($params)
    {
        $header = [];
        ksort($params);

        foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            $header[] = rawurlencode($key).'="'.rawurlencode($value).'"';
        }

        return implode(', ', $header);
    }

    private function generateNonce()
    {
        return Str::random(20);
    }

    private function parseResponse($response)
    {
        parse_str($response, $parsed);

        return $parsed;
    }
}

I am trying to authenticate the user from my app to netsuite using the 3 step authorization flow. After clicking on allow to authenticate the app, I get an Invalid Attempt to Login 'USER_ERROR'. what I expect is for the post request to return the access token and secret object.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_157652573296.html has example input values, and shows what signature you are supposed to create based on those. Have you verified, that what your code produces with those values, is a match?
